# Могут ли злоумышленники давать экстремистские комментарии во вконтакте c ip юзера?

Tags: вконтакте, безопасность, доступ

Предположим к Ивану Ивановичу пришли утром с обыском из центра "Э", потому что кто-то с его аккаунта и его `ip` запостил очень лестные пожелания в адрес правительства. 
Иван Иванович пытается выстроить защиту таким образом:

1. За компьютером Иван Ивановича не было, но комп был включен.
2. Комп Иван Иваныча был заражен вирусом и как следствие, подключён к вражескому бот-нету, предположительно в `hidden`. Следовательно, экстремистский комментарий дал не Иван Иванович, а искусственный интеллект фирмы `hidden` к примеру.
3. Вредноносное программное обеспечение вероятно самоудалилось, а следовательно следов на компьютере можно и не найти.

**Вопрос:** Возможна ли в принципе такая ситуация, что вредноносное ПО будет самостоятельно давать экстремистские комментарии вконтакте, или хотя бы сохранять экстремистские фотографии таким образом, что сайт запишет `ip` Иван Ивановича?

**Второй вопрос**: можно ли (и как?) получив компьютер юзера и имея данные по входу (ip, время) аргументировано опровергнуть такую версию, доказав, что это был именно Иван Иванович?

Comment: Если захотят посадить, то никакая экспертиза не спасёт.

Comment: "Вредноносное программное обеспечение вероятно самоудалилось, а следовательно следов на компьютере можно и не найти." - это в какой вселенной невозможно найти следов?

Comment: А они и следы искать не будут. Как недавно объясняли в одной передаче, сейчас и эксперты и следователи подчиняются одному начальству и "эксперт" при обследовании компьютера напишет то, что нужно следователю. Как пример приводили ситуацию, что по ошибке эксперту отдали вообще не тот комп на исследование и он на нем "нашел" все что полагалось найти для дела. Только на суде выяснилось при вскрытии пакета с вещьдоком, что комп не тот и там разумеется не было ничего, что "нашли" ... А привлекать сторонних экспертов суд обычно не дает

Comment: @Suvitruf мы говорим о доказательных формальностях с точки зрения компьютерных специалистов. Особенности юрисдикции нас не интересуют.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin ваш компьютер вообще ни чем помочь не может. Они смотрят IP в базе VK. А потом смотрят, кто в тот момент выходил с этим IP.

Comment: тем более что на компе вообще не обязано быть следов что вы с него писали, может вы приватный режим включили или вообще к своему домашнему роутеру другой комп подключали, который потом выбросили.

Comment: @Mike это тоже понятно. Вопрос чисто теоретический. Можно ли включить комп юзера в ботнет, чтобы он давал экстремистские комменты таким образом, чтобы были все следы, как будто это сам юзер делал. Забегая вперёд, можно ли теоретически получить доступ к личному компу герцога Плесского, чтобы он написал 100 интересных комментов?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin можно.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin конечно можно. IP будет одинаковый, хоть это юзер делал или нет. А если вредоносное ПО не найдут, или не захотят найти, тогда уже никак не докажешь что это не сам юзер

Comment: Есть один прецедент. Человек подключился к общедоступной вафле, подтвердил номер телефона, вся фигня. Злоумышленник хакнул вафлю и перехватывал все подключения (там данные в хэше телефона+номер сессии + еще что-то хранятся). После того, как герой отошел от данной зоны, злоумышленник подключился через хэш героя к вафле (опустим подробности, как именно он это сделал) и закупил айфонов на кругленькую сумму через кардинг. Естественно, все это дошло до отдела "К", после чего герою истории потребовалось 11 месяцев, чтобы доказать, что это был не он. И это повезло, поскольку там было видеонаблюдение.

Comment: С юридической стороны, там будет Ваш IP и Ваш аккаунт, что, в теории, не является весомым аргументом в качестве обвинения, но нашей системе правосудия на это, мягко говоря, пофиг

Comment: В такие моменты начинаешь понимать, насколько важен VPN или прокси

Comment: @Samilton за использование которых однажды тоже начнут садить ;)

Comment: Прошу прощения за оффтоп, но зачем вообще нормальному человеку вконтакт, если за него сажают? Или для чего нормальному человеку распространять свою персональную информацию налево-направо? Рассказывать всем прохожим, где он сегодня был и что делал? Я реально не понимаю предназначения таких сайтов. Мне кажется, что вк уже давно принадлежит правительству рф и пользуются им сегодня только депутаты, судьи, да дураки.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf спасибо, вы правы но вопрос не в этом был. Если вы знаете ещё (помимо того, что ответил человек ниже) возможности, что комментил **x**, а пришли к **y** пожалуйста дайте свой ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробую ответить:

Что необходимо, для того чтобы от имени пользователя/пользователей постить комментарии и/или экстремистские фото:

1) CSRF-уязвимость на сайте vk.com

2) XSS-уязвимость на сайте vk.com

3) Умение эксплуатировать данные уязвимости

Что не нужно, для того чтобы от имени пользователя/пользователей постить комментарии и/или экстремистские фото:

1) Ботнет не нужен

Сценарий:

Злоумышленник находит на сайте CSRF или XSS, грамотно эксплуатирует данные уязвимости, и комментарий написать, или фото опубликовать может хоть сам Медведев. Доказать, что это сделал не Медведев практически невозможно, с такими законами.

[Пофикшенные дыры, которые позволяли проделывать многое/незаконное, и не только](https://hackerone.com/vkcom/hacktivity)

Comment: Вы красавчик, я готов принять ваш ответ, только дополните пожалуйста ссылками на АИ (прецеденты использования уязвимостей, прецеденты взлома и т.д.). И плюс только за то, что мыслите правильно - по сути (я так полагаю), админка вконтакте может подтасовать метаданные легко и непринужденно.

Comment: И это всё тоже не обязательно, достаточно добиться выполнения произвольного кода на компьютере пользователя любым способом, например подсунув ему котики.jpg.exe

Comment: @andreymal вариантов - туева хуча! Важно то, как выстроить защиту, в случае, если к вам приедут! А выстроить её легко. Как вариант, гнуть линию, что это дыра вк. И пусть доказывают, что это не дыра, а я!

Comment: @misdeed,если вы правы, так получается то что юзер не давал комментарии (а к примеру отдыхал в деревне Мухосранские Творожки у тещи без интернета) совсем не гарантируют то, что за ним не придут.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin конечно же за ним придут. В этом вся соль нашего правосудия)))

Comment: @AndrewKachalin ...Причем, придут за ним именно в Мухосранские Творожки))

Comment: @misdeed немного ваша ссылка не понравилась. Там об уязвимостях может прочитать только человек с регистрацией. Конечно полезно знать что есть такой сайт, но всё же дайте нам АИ такие, что хоть баба Валя могла перейти по ссылке.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, прочитать детали уязвимости может любой пользователь, если уязвимость full disclose. Ну, а если vk не раскрыли детали бага, значит посчитали, что данный баг, и детали бага не должны вообще попасть в паблик.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, чем вам не то, что вам нужно:? https://hackerone.com/reports/211072 (Однако, vk и автор репорта посчитали, что нет необходимости раскрывать детали уязвимости)

Comment: @misdeed ещё хочу ссылок, авторитетных заключений, дабы все 620 жертв репрессий с уверенностью смотрели судьям в глаза.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin судьям смотреть не надо. Если вы уверены в том, что не вы постили комменты/фото - просите у прокурора форенсики, или поручите своему адвокату сделать это за вас.

Comment: @misdeed мне так нравится оборот "если не вы". Я то - нет, за мной не придут. Просто хочется техническими знаниями  помочь той тысяче несправедливо осужденных.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, а помочь им будет трудно. В связи с тем, что они ни бум-бум, ни в Ай-ти, ни в ИБ.